# ES6 type error when assigning default values in constructor

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am quite new to `es6`. Below is my simple `Student` class with a constructor accepting 2 arguments. I am assigning default values by calling function in the constructor signature itself, when the arguments are not passed.

```
class Student {

    defaultRno = () => -1;
    defaultName = () => "unknown";

    /**
     * The default constructor
     */
    constructor(regNo = this.defaultRno(), name = this.defaultName()) {
        this.regNo = regNo;
        this.name = name;
    }

    setRegNo = (rno = this.defaultRno()) => this.regNo = rno;
    setName = (name = this.defaultName()) => this.name = name;

    displayConsole = () => console.log(`Reg.No# ${this.regNo}\nName: ${this.name}`);

}
// create student object
var stu = new Student();
stu.displayConsole();
```

This is resulting with below error:

```
index.js:9Uncaught TypeError: this.defaultRno is not a function
    at new Student (index.js:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f01272b…:555)
```

When I change the constructor like below, the error is not seen:

```
constructor(regNo = -1, name = 'unknown') {
        this.regNo = regNo;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

UPDATE:
The same way of initiating default values works with function. Check `setRegNo` and `setName` above. I observed it is not working with constructor.

Comment: At the time the parameters to the constructor are evaluated, and defaults applied, the object is not fully constructed, and is still missing methods like `defaultRno`. Is there some reason you cannot just write `constructor(regNo = -1, name = "unknown")`?

Comment: That's not ES6. You are using an experimental transpiler plugin, and you don't understand what the class field syntax does.

Comment: Arrow functions in a class body are not going to work the way you want. You can however use shorthand method declarations like `setRegNo() { }`.

Comment: @torazaburo, I am just exploring the possible ways of assigning default values. The same kind of code works with function (check `setRegNo` function in my question), but I observed it is not working with constructor.

Comment: @Bergi that's definitely es6

Comment: @Maxwelll "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =*". Class fields are not ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the constructor method is how you initialize an object created with a class in javascript - `this` will always be an empty object if you are trying to access it within the function parameters of the constructor itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions

```
class Foo {
    constructor(foo = () => console.log(this), bar = () => console.log('baz')) {
      foo(); // {}
      bar(); // baz
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();
```

https://repl.it/HnjB/2

Comment: That makes sense. Is the class also undefined though? What about constructor(foo = Student.defaultRno())

Comment: @JeremyLawsonyou can actually access static methods defined on the class from within the constructor function params. The class is not `undefined`...

https://repl.it/HnjB/5